# Print smarty var in link file param

Tags: smarty, shopware

One simple thing: 
I want to combine the `{s name="*"}` and `{link file="*"}` blocks.

```
src="{link file='{s name='sFooterPaymentsIcon'}{/s}'}"
```

The problems should be the

> '

signs.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try assign a new variable and pass that on file parameter, like:

```
{assign var="my_file" value="{s name='sFooterPaymentsIcon'}{/s}"}
```

and then

```
src="{link file="$my_file"}"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
//Assign snippet value to variable $snippetLink, in case variable is empty - assign LinkInCaseSnippetEmpty
{assign var='snippetLink' value='LinkInCaseSnippetEmpty'|snippet:'TheNameOfSnippet':"Namespace/If/Need"}
//assign source from variable $snippetLink
src="{link file=$my_file}"
```

In one line:

```
src="{link file='LinkInCaseSnippetEmpty'|snippet:'TheNameOfSnippet':'Namespace/If/Need'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

`{s}` is for for text-snippets and should not be used for configuration-variables. If you need to make an include configurable, you should create a plugin for that.

The plugin should have a frontend-subscriber and make the file-include configurable via backend configuration-form. In the subscriber you can pass the configuration-value for the file-include to the frontend-view.